# SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol while running perl script

Tags: perl, ssl, lwp

@Steffen: I will check on script part.
I just noticed that wget command to service now url not able to establish SSL connection

`[root@XXXX rpms]# wget https://testuser:testpwd.service-now.com/u_incident_interface.do
--2018-06-10 13:00:07--  https://srv_SOAPimporterNagios:password@rwe.service-now.com/u_incident_interface.do
Resolving rwestproxy-neurathdc.rwe.com... 10.88.253.20
Connecting to rwestproxy-neurathdc.rwe.com|10.88.253.20|:8080... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
[root@XXXX rpms]#`

Can you advice on SSL connection issue?

Comment: Without a code example which shows the failure I fear you'll have very few responses....

Comment: It's impossible to know what is going wrong without seeing the code that causes the error. Please show us a really short example of code which triggers this behaviour. Specifically, what is the URL you're trying to fetch?

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is very big script and using lot of perl modules.

Comment: I am trying to connect https url

Comment: Which module are you using for doing SOAP?

Comment: SOAP::Lite,
IO::Socket::SSL,
LWP::Protocol::https
These are main three modules we are using for script

Comment: @vani: Please don't add your code in a comment where it is hard to read. Instead, edit your question and add it there where it can be properly formatted and readable.

Comment: @vani: *It is very big script and using lot of perl modules* Which is why I asked you to cut it down to a short example.

Comment: Looks like the only useful bit in the code you've given us is `$soapSnHandle->call($soapCommand => @soapParams)`. But we also need to know what is all of those variables.

Comment: @vani: Please **[edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50761495/edit)** to add these details. Code is unreadable in comments.

Comment: @vani: I can't see where `$soapSnHandle` or `$soapCommand` are created. And, you show us where `@soapParams` is created, but you use another mystery variable, `$number` in its creation, so we're really no closer to being able to help. What we need is a simple (probably four or five lines) example that we can just run to see the problem that you're seeing. Cut out any extraneous crap like config files or things like that. Use hard-code values if necessary. Just create all the variables you need and then make the SOAP call.

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR: Server is responding with plain traffic instead of the expected TLS. Cause of this might be wrong expectations on the client, misconfiguration or old buggy software.

> SSL connect attempt failed error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Errors like `unknown protocol` or also `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`  or `wrong version number` usually happen if the other device does not properly talk SSL at all. This means the client is initiating the TLS handshake with the ClientHello and the server is responding with something which does not resemble SSL/TLS at all. Still the client will try to interpret the non-TLS answer as TLS and thus will complain about some strange TLS version or some corrupted TLS record.

This happens typically if one is trying to **talk to plain HTTP server with HTTPS**. It might be because the **server was never configured for HTTPS in the first place** and one is wrongly assuming that changing the URL from `http://` to `https://` will magically make the server HTTPS ready. It might also be that that one is **accessing the wrong port** at the server, i.e. the plain HTTP port and not the HTTPS port. And there are also cases where due to a **misconfiguration of the server** only speaks plain HTTP while the config looks like it should speak HTTPS - like in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/915721/configure-apache-with-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificates-leads-to-ssl-error-rx-recor/915732#915732). Or it might be because of a wrong proxy configuration, i.e. **assuming that a proxy will be accessed by HTTPS** wheres it is accessed by plain HTTP even for HTTPS URL like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852041/perl-lwpuseragent-https-proxy-to-specific-https-web-site-unknown-protocol-er).

It can also happen if the **server needs some initial plain data before switching to TLS**. This is for example when using a proxy to connect to the final target. In case of a HTTP proxy the client needs to send a plain HTTP `CONNECT` request first, read the plain HTTP response from the server and check for success and only then can start with the TLS handshake. This situation can happen for example if you are using an **older version of LWP** since between 6.00 and 6.06 proxy support for HTTPS was broken.

Comment: Thank You very much for your response.

Let me explain the background of the issue. We have a environment of nagios monitoring tool with servicenow ticketing tool for incident creation.

We have recently upgraded the RHEL OS from 6.7 to 6.9.. from there problem started on creating servicenow incidents.

I checked the LWP::UserAgent version.. it is 6.15.


Could you please provide me any simple script which client make connection to server and server respond to client ?

Comment: @vani: I cannot create such a script since I have not enough information about your environment. But have a look at the examples and the rest of the [documentation for LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) which also includes information on how to configure a proxy.

Comment: I will check on script part. I just noticed that wget command to service now url not able to establish SSL connection 


[root@XXXX rpms]# wget https://testuser:testpwd.service-now.com/u_incident_interface.do
--2018-06-10 13:00:07--  https://srv_SOAPimporterNagios:password@rwe.service-now.com/u_incident_interface.do
Resolving rwestproxy-neurathdc.rwe.com... 10.88.253.20
Connecting to rwestproxy-neurathdc.rwe.com|10.88.253.20|:8080... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
[root@XXXX rpms]#


Can you advice on SSL connection issue?

Comment: @vani: I have no idea what exactly you are doing and maybe you don't have it either. But, it looks like that you are trying to connect to some proxy with HTTPS, which as I already said in my answer is probably wrong. There is probably somewhere an environment variable you don't show, i.e. something like `https_proxy=https://rwestproxy-neurathdc.rwe.com:8080`. This should probably be `https_proxy=http://rwestproxy-neurathdc.rwe.com:8080` instead, i.e. `http://` not `https://` to access the proxy.

Comment: I am trying to call service now url from my RHEL server using wget command.. but I am receiving Unable to establish SSL connection.. and my wget version is GNU Wget 1.12 built on linux-gnu

Comment: @vani: have you processed my statements about improper configuration of your proxy settings and looked into it?

Comment: Yes Steffen. I made the proxy as suggested by You. but still same SSL issue.

Comment: @vani: please make sure that both `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables are set to the correct (`http://..`) proxy. wget seems to use the first only.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

I have created the script to connect service-now and make soap calls, but script failing with below error.......

Searching for Change Request... SOAP::Lite=HASH(0x22da840) and SOAP::Data=HASH(0x2e1bf38)
500 handshakefailed at soap_connection.pl line 29.

Comment: use SOAP::Lite;
$ENV{https_proxy} = "http://myproxy.rwe.com:8080"; 
$ENV{HTTPS_PROXY} = "http://myproxy-neurathdc.rwe.com:8080"; 

sub SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials {                      return "k" => "l"; 
}
$soap = SOAP::Lite -> proxy('https://usr_soap:pwd_soap@swe.service-now.com/change_request.do?SOAP');
my $method = SOAP::Data->name('getRecords') ->attr({xmlns => 'https://www.service-now.com/'});
my @params = (
         SOAP::Data->name(number => $ARGV[0])
);
print "Searching for Change Request";
my $result = $soap->call($method => @params);
</code>

Comment: @vani: so wget works now or not? Also, the proxy setting for `https_proxy` in your script does not reflect the syntax required by LWP (see documentation).

Comment: With wget we are able to connect service-now.
We are using SOAP::Lite syntax.

Comment: @vani: SOAP::Lite uses LWP as base. Please try with LWP::UserAgent but set `https_proxy` correctly, i.e. `http://host:8080` and not `host:8080` and either use the `env_proxy` method so that it gets the proxy from environment or use the `proxy` method as documented for LWP::UserAgent

Comment: @Steffan: As suggested I have created script to use LWP::UserAgent and I am using LWP 5.833 version. but still connection failing.

#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use LWP::UserAgent;
use SOAP::Lite;
use Data::Dumper;

$ENV{https_proxy} = "http://rproxy-hdc.rwe.com:8080";
$ENV{HTTPS_PROXY} = "http://rproxy-hdc.rwe.com:8080";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->env_proxy;

my $response = $ua -> get('https://soap_user:soap_pwd@dev.service-now.com/?WSDL');

if ($response->is_success) {
     print "Connection success";  
}
else {
     print "Connection failed";  
}

Any ideas please ?

Comment: @vani:  *I am using LWP __5.833__ version*  - I'm actually shocked about this since I've not expected you to use a version of LWP which is nearly 9 years old. And it actually conflicts with a statement you've made earlier about you using LWP 6.15. Using such an old version also means that you are using the old Crypt::SSLeay backend and very likely a version of OpenSSL which does not support modern protocols like TLS 1.2. It is no surprise that you run into trouble when using such an ancient software stack today. Please use up-to-date software.

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue by updating the LWP module to 6.34 and adding below lines in script
$ENV{https_proxy} = http://proxy:8080
$ENV{HTTPS_PROXY} = http://proxy:8080
$ENV{PERL_LWP_ENV_PROXY} = 1;

Thanks for all your help.